# How to conveniently use Ubuntu with a Mac keyboard, using the MAC meaning of keys?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, keyboard, terminal, keymap

I access Ubuntu via Barrier keyboard sharing software. The keyboard is on a mac book.
This functionally works but there is much cognitive overload with switching between the different key meanings.
90% of this is copy/paste. Especially from the command shell. On the Mac I use iTerm2. I've recently tried using Kitty on Ubuntu and it is OK but I would quickly use something different to achieve my ergonomic goals.

I would like to be able to use the MAC style copy/paste everywhere in Ubuntu (CMD-C/CMD-V). I would also prefer that copy/paste in the Ubuntu terminal worked as close to the Mac functionality as possible. In Kitty, CTRL-SHIFT-C and CTRL-SHIFT-V are quite a pain.

I am not against changing configurations on the Ubuntu side, as long as I can make it work like changing a profile. Because Barrier does crash and the easiest way to avoid confusion with a normal PC keyboard is to just change the profile back to 'Normal' mode instead of 'Mac' mode.

I've googled a bunch and have only seen partial solutions. I would appreciate any insight from anyone achieving this or knowledge from attempters that prove the effort is in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Barrier supports the ability to redefine each modifier key on each client individually.

On your Barrier server, click Configure Server
Double-click the icon for your desired client
On the right side, there is a section labeled Modifier Keys

Several of the common modifier keys are listed.

I forget which name refers to the Mac "Apple" key - either Meta or Super. Mac users often like to swap the Control and Apple keys in order to be able to use the same physical key positions for common functions, like Copy and Paste as you noted.